# "Bypassing" a mock in Quarkus unit testing

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a Quarkus project where I have most of the business logic placed in services, aka injectable beans using @ApplicationScoped annotations, where all of the CRUD operations take place. In the JAX-RS resource files themselves, the bulk of the logic is just validation, often using whole validation beans. This has meant that we needed to mock our injected services when we tested the resources, to prevent the unit tests from becoming essentially integration tests. We do this having a structure like this (example project);

[image]

The file MockGreetingService.java in turn looks like this:

```
import io.quarkus.test.Mock;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
public class MockGreetingService extends GreetingService {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s, your id is %s", name, "1234");
    }
}
```

Our actual project is a bit more sophisticated than this in the way that the mocks always return our DTO classes regardless of input, but the principle is the same as above. They work flawlessly for our JAX-RS resource tests. However, trying to test the actual service beans themselves means problems with this setup. I built a service test, which uses the same annotations and flow as the code below:

```
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@QuarkusTest
public class GreetingServiceTest {

    @Inject
    GreetingService greetingService;

    @Test
    void checkReturnsHello () {

        String result = greetingService.sayHello();
        System.out.println(result);
        Assertions.assertEquals("hello Martin! Your country is Italy", result);
    }
}
```

With the dependency injection in the class above, which we don't do in our resource tests, I expected Quarkus to understand that we want to use the original service in this test. How foolish of me. A simple log has shown that the mock service methods indeed still run in the latter test above.

Now I wonder - is it a way to disable the mock for this latter test? Preferably without having to modify or remove the mock classes, although I realize that might not be possible in the way I imagine it to be. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for qualifiers, which enable you to have different implementation beans, and to choose at the injection point which type of bean you prefer:
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#qualifiers

As an alternative, you may also decide to instantiate your service on your own, not using cdi in any way.

Comment: Tried using the @Named annotation in the link you sent and it works for the test project. I will come back tomorrow and mark this as the solution provided it also works for the real project, which is much more complex.

Comment: Confirmed working on the full-scale project.

Thanks!